# Oracle- Does executing simultaneous queries affect their performances?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using very large tables containing hundreds of millions of rows, and I am measuring the performances of some queries using SQL Developer, I figured out that there is an option called Unshared SQL worksheet, it allows me to execute many queries at the same time. Executing many queries at the same time is suitable for me especially that some queries or procedure take hours to be executed.

My question is does executing many queries at the same time affect performances? (by performances I mean the duration of execution of queries)

Comment: Yes.  The query load on the database affects performance.

Comment: Thank you f or this quick answer, It makes sense even though I hoped the opposite

Comment: Why were you hoping the opposite? The opposite **could** be true, if the queries were small (they didn't do a lot of heavy computations) and the data was small (not a lot of read from / write to disk and not a big footprint in memory) - in that case, you might have two queries that each runs in 5 seconds separately, run in parallel in the same 5 seconds instead. But you described just the opposite - massive data, long-running queries; almost certainly resources would be fully utilized, in which case something has to give.

Answer (score 1):

Every query costs something to execute. That's just physics. Your database has a fixed amount of resources - CPU, memory, I/O, temp disk - to service queries (let's leave elastic cloud instances out of the picture). Every query which is executing simultaneously is asking for resources from that fixed pot. Potentially, if you run too many queries at the same time you will run into resource contention, which will affect the performance of individual queries.

Note the word *"potentially"*. Whether you will run into actual problem depends on many things: what resources your queries need, how efficiently your queries have been written, how much resource your database server has available, how efficiently it's been configured to support multiple users (and whether the DBA has implemented profiles to manage resource usage). So, like with almost every database tuning question, the answer is "it depends".

This is true even for queries which hit massive tables such as you describe. Although, if you have queries which you know will take hours to run you might wish to consider tuning them as a matter of priority.

Comment: I think it is normal that it takes that time if the tables contain hundred of millions of rows and some column are nested arrays...Only to update them is a heavy task, even a simple insert query could take hours.